# How to distribute an integer number across bins by probability

Tags: python

I have an integer value `k` and a list of probabilities which sum to 1. I want to create a new list which breaks up `k` into smaller integers according to the probabilities in my list.

The issues are that I do not know the size of my list in advance and multiple probabilities in my list could be small and equal, so my new list doesn't always sum to `k`.

For example:

```
> k = 10
> l = [0.12, 0.12, 0.04, 0.04, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.27, 0.27]
> sum(l)
1.0
> new_l = [int(round(k*v)) for v in a]
> print(new_l)
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3]
> sum(new_l)
8
```

How can I enforce that `sum(new_l) == k`?

Maybe this isn't even possible, at least with my method. Even if `k` is larger than `len(l)`, if `k` is odd it doesn't seem to ever work:

```
>>> for k in [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20, 50, 75, 101, 1001, 1002, 10001, 10002, 100001, 100002]:
...     print(k, sum([round(k*v,0) for v in a]))
... 
(10, 8.0)
(11, 8.0)
(12, 8.0)
(13, 14.0)
(14, 14.0)
(15, 14.0)
(16, 14.0)
(20, 18.0)
(50, 52.0)
(75, 76.0)
(101, 100.0)
(1001, 1000.0)
(1002, 1002.0)
(10001, 10000.0)
(10002, 10002.0)
(100001, 100000.0)
(100002, 100002.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
k = 10
l = [0.12, 0.12, 0.04, 0.04, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.27, 0.27]
targets = [k*v for v in l]
new_l = [ int(v) for v in targets]

while sum(new_l) < k:
    residuals = [ t - v for t,v in zip(targets, new_l) ]
    index = residuals.index( max(residuals) )
    new_l[index] += 1
```

This starts by finding the largest integer `n` such that `n` is less than `k*v`, then fixing it up by incrementing the worst n until the `sum(new_l) == k`. It will never take more than O(len(l)) operations to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this the wrong way. What you are trying to do is select an option from your list `n` times. This can be achieved using the `numpy.random.choice` function.

Here is corresponding code:

```
from numpy.random import choice
from collections import Counter
draw = choice(range(12), 100,
              p=[0.12, 0.12, 0.04, 0.04, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.27, 0.27])
counter = Counter(draw)
print(counter.values())
print(sum(counter.values()))
```

This will output:

```
dict_values([16, 13, 7, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 31, 19])
100
```

Comment: although it doesn't answer the asker's specific question, I do wonder if this is a good alternative way to solve the root problem that the asker wants.

Comment: I think it does answer it. I'll edit the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: I like your "thinking outside the box". The result the OP is looking for could be generated from your counter using `[counter.get(i, 0) for i in range(n)]`. However, I'm not sure if this is a valid answer for the question. At least the result of this method is non-deterministic. But the actual requirements for the solution are not defined yet, and this *is* a solution that satisfies the only requirement stated in the question (at this moment), since the sum of the result is guaranteed to be correct ;-)

Comment: NB: In Python 3 you could use the built-in `random.choices()` instead of `numpy.random.choice()` to avoid a dependency on numpy.

Comment: Interesting solution! But `len(counter.values()) < len(p)` if `k=10` in the above sample. Unclear where the zeros should be.

Comment: @Sal, if you add `print([counter.get(i, 0) for i in range(12)])` at the end, it will yield the result in the format you were expecting.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by randomization:

```
sl = np.cumsum(l) # cumulative probability
b = np.random.rand(10) # a random number for each of your integers

new_l = np.zeros(l.shape)    
for i in range(k):
    iinsert = np.where(b[i]>sl)[0][0] # first entry where b is larger than the cumumlative prob
    new_l[iinsert] += 1
```